# How to reset the close reason when close is cancelled

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

**Question**

> Is it possible to reset the [CloseReason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.closereason%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by the [FormClosingEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the [FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of a modal dialog?

**Symptoms**

Setting the `DialogResult` of a modal dialog can result in an *"incorrect"* `CloseReason` if the close event have previously been cancelled.

**Details**

*(The following code is just sample code to highlight the inconvenience)*

Imagine I have a form with two buttons, *OK* and *Cancel*, displayed as a modal dialog.

```
Me.btnOk = New Button With {.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK}
Me.btnCancel = New Button With {.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel}

Me.AcceptButton = Me.btnOk
Me.CancelButton = Me.btnCancel
```

Any attempts to close the form will be cancelled.

If I click each button (including the `[X]` - close form button) in the following order, the close reasons will be as following:

*Case 1*

- `btnOk`::::::::::: *None*
- `btnCancel`::: *None*
- `X`::::::::::::::::::: *UserClosing*

Now, if I repeat the steps you'll see that the `UserClosing` reason will persist:

- `btnOk`::::::::::: *UserClosing*
- `btnCancel`::: *UserClosing*
- `X`::::::::::::::::::: *UserClosing*

*Case 2*

- `X`::::::::::::::::::: *UserClosing*
- `btnCancel`::: *UserClosing*
- `btnOk`::::::::::: *UserClosing*

Same here. Once you click the `X` button the close reason will always return `UserClosing`.

**Sample application**

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.Text = "Test"
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.ClientSize = New Size(75, 25)
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        Me.btnOpenDialog = New Button() With {.TabIndex = 0, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill, .Text = "Open dialog"}
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.btnOpenDialog)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleOpenDialog(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenDialog.Click
        Using instance As New CustomDialog()
            instance.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents btnOpenDialog As Button

    Private Class CustomDialog
        Inherits Form

        Public Sub New()
            Me.Text = "Custom dialog"
            Me.ClientSize = New Size(400, 200)
            Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent
            Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog
            Me.MinimizeBox = False
            Me.MaximizeBox = False
            Me.tbOutput = New RichTextBox() With {.TabIndex = 0, .Bounds = New Rectangle(0, 0, 400, 155), .ReadOnly = True, .ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.ForcedBoth, .WordWrap = True}
            Me.btnExit = New Button With {.TabIndex = 3, .Text = "Exit", .Bounds = New Rectangle(10, 165, 75, 25), .Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left)}
            Me.btnOk = New Button With {.TabIndex = 1, .Text = "OK", .Bounds = New Rectangle(237, 165, 75, 25), .Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Right), .DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK}
            Me.btnCancel = New Button With {.TabIndex = 2, .Text = "Cancel", .Bounds = New Rectangle(315, 165, 75, 25), .Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Right), .DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel}
            Me.Controls.AddRange({Me.tbOutput, Me.btnExit, Me.btnOk, Me.btnCancel})
            Me.AcceptButton = Me.btnOk
            Me.CancelButton = Me.btnCancel
        End Sub

        Private Sub HandleExitDialog(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
            Me.exitPending = True
            Me.Close()
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
            If (Not Me.exitPending) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Me.tbOutput.Text += (String.Format("DialogResult={0}, CloseReason={1}{2}", Me.DialogResult.ToString(), e.CloseReason.ToString(), Environment.NewLine))
                Me.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None
            End If
            MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
        End Sub

        Private exitPending As Boolean

        Private WithEvents btnExit As Button
        Private WithEvents btnCancel As Button
        Private WithEvents btnOk As Button
        Private WithEvents tbOutput As RichTextBox

    End Class

End Class
```

## Update

I was of the impression that if either the `Form.AcceptButton` or `Form.CancelButton`  ([IButtonControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ibuttoncontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) was clicked the close reason would be set to `UserClosing`, but this is not the case. In the following code you'll see that all it do is setting the `DialogResult` of the owning form to that of its own `DialogResult`.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim form As Form = MyBase.FindFormInternal
    If (Not form Is Nothing) Then
        form.DialogResult = Me.DialogResult
    End If
    MyBase.AccessibilityNotifyClients(AccessibleEvents.StateChange, -1)
    MyBase.AccessibilityNotifyClients(AccessibleEvents.NameChange, -1)
    MyBase.OnClick(e)
End Sub
```

The `Control` class *do* have a property named `CloseReason` but it's defined as `Friend`, thus not accessible.

I also thought that setting the forms `DialogResult` would result in a `WM` message being sent, but all it does is setting a private field.

So I delved into reflector and followed the stack. The following image is a **highly simplified** illustration.

[image: Stack]

This is how the `CheckCloseDialog` method looks like:

```
Friend Function CheckCloseDialog(ByVal closingOnly As Boolean) As Boolean
    If ((Me.dialogResult = DialogResult.None) AndAlso MyBase.Visible) Then
        Return False
    End If
    Try
        Dim e As New FormClosingEventArgs(Me.closeReason, False)
        If Not Me.CalledClosing Then
            Me.OnClosing(e)
            Me.OnFormClosing(e)
            If e.Cancel Then
                Me.dialogResult = DialogResult.None
            Else
                Me.CalledClosing = True
            End If
        End If
        If (Not closingOnly AndAlso (Me.dialogResult <> DialogResult.None)) Then
            Dim args2 As New FormClosedEventArgs(Me.closeReason)
            Me.OnClosed(args2)
            Me.OnFormClosed(args2)
            Me.CalledClosing = False
        End If
    Catch exception As Exception
        Me.dialogResult = DialogResult.None
        If NativeWindow.WndProcShouldBeDebuggable Then
            Throw
        End If
        Application.OnThreadException(exception)
    End Try
    If (Me.dialogResult = DialogResult.None) Then
        Return Not MyBase.Visible
    End If
    Return True
End Function
```

As you can see the modal message loop checks the `DialogResult` in every cycle and if the conditions are met it will use the *stored* `CloseReason` (as observed) when creating the `FormClosingEventArgs`.

**Summary**

Yes, I know that the `IButtonControl` interface have a `PerformClick` method which you can call programmatically, but still, IMO this smells like a bug. If clicking a button is **not** a result of a user action then what is?

Comment: have you tried clicking cancel, ok, X - in that order? not sure the reason, but UserClosing is set when being closed by script as well. or it may just be an oversight. i'd have to test this.

Comment: Tried using the OnClosing event on the Form, didn't work. Tried sending a new event to MyBase, didn't work. So I am rather stumped. Looking forward for an answer here :)

Comment: @porkchop Yes, I have. It returns `None, None, UserClosing`. And if you repeat this, it will return `UserClosing` whichever button you click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably call that a bug.

As you mentioned, the CloseReason property is marked internal (or Friend in VB.Net terms) so one work-around to the problem is using Reflection to reset that value yourself:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(e As FormClosingEventArgs)
  If Not exitPending Then
    e.Cancel = True
    tbOutput.AppendText(String.Format("DialogResult={0}, CloseReason={1}{2}", _
                        Me.DialogResult.ToString(), e.CloseReason.ToString(), _
                        Environment.NewLine))
    Dim pi As PropertyInfo
    pi = Me.GetType.GetProperty("CloseReason", _
                                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    pi.SetValue(Me, CloseReason.None, Nothing)
  End If
  MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

No guarantee that this code would work on future versions of WinForms, but I'm guessing it's a safe bet these days.  :-)

Comment: Uhm, since when (and please don't say always) were we allowed to set an internal/friend field contained in an another module other than your own? Doesn't this break the *"Access modifier model"*? Because: Wow, this is actually **working**! We all know that if you're to create an application a bit more complicated then `Hello world`, at some point, you'll need to subclass every control you're using. However, if I knew this before, then maybe two or three controls could have been spared.

Comment: interesting. still have to handle the other closereasons properly though, or you'll end up in trouble.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I believe Reflection was there from the beginning (or at least .Net 2.0).  It can be a dangerous weapon.  Obviously, the owners of a class that mark things *internal* or *private* do so for a reason: the implementation might change in the future.  Mucking with those things can lead to a future bug in your code, so proceed with caution.

Comment: To be honest, I've never tried to changed an internal field as I thought it would throw an exception. Internal is internal right? Think again. You learn something new every day they say.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm sorry for addressing this here but did you flag this [potential bounty fraud](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842008/set-caret-position-to-last-character-in-masked-text-box-winform/25848292)? Suddenly both the bounty and your comment were removed.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Yeah, the two users looked funny to me so I flagged it and a moderator came and closed the one sock-puppet account.  The current user has a tendency to just accept his own answers anyway so there isn't much of a point in trying to help a user like that.

Comment: @LarsTech That's great! I was stunned by seeing a bounty offered, answer and rewarded, all within a minute or so. You see, I've been battling the infamous *losung* fraud ring for many months now and the last I need is new opponents.

Answer (score 8):

It is pretty important to understand why this is behaving the way it does, you are liable to get yourself into trouble when you rely in the CloseReason too much.  This is not a bug, it is a  restriction due to the way Windows was designed.  One core issue is the way the [WM_CLOSE message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is formulated, it is the one that sets the train in motion, first firing the FormClosing event.

This message can be sent for *lots* of reasons, you are familiar with the common ones.  But that's not where it ends, other programs can send that message as well.  You can tell the "flaw" from the MSDN Library article I linked to, the message is missing a WPARAM value that encodes the *intent* of the message.  So there isn't any way for a program to provide a reasonable CloseReason back to you.  Winforms is forced to *guess* at a reason.  It is of course an entirely imperfect guess.

That's not where it ends, the DialogResult property is a problem as well.  It will force a dialog to close when *any* code assigns that property.  But again the same problem, there isn't any way for such code to indicate the *intent* of the assignment.  So it doesn't, it leaves in internal Form.CloseReason property at whatever value it had before, None by default.

This was "properly" implemented in .NET 1.0, there was only the Closing event and it didn't give a reason at all.  But that didn't work out so well either, apps that used it chronically prevented Windows from shutting down.  They just didn't know that it was inappropriate to, say, display a message box.  The .NET 2.0 FormClosing event was added as a workaround for that.  But it needs to work with the imperfect guess.

It is important to rate the CloseReason values, some are very accurate and some are just guesses:

- CloseReason.WindowsShutdown - reliable
- CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall - reliable
- CloseReason.MdiFormClosing - reliable, not very useful
- CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing - reliable, not very useful
- CloseReason.TaskManagerClosing - complete guess, will be returned when *any* program sends a WM_CLOSE message, not just Task Manager
- CloseReason.UserClosing - complete guess, will also be returned when your program calls the Close() method for example
- CloseReason.None - it just doesn't know.

Yes, Winforms not setting the CloseReason back to None when your FormClosing event handler cancels is arguably a bug.  But it isn't the kind of bug that actually really matters.  Since you can't treat UserClosing and None differently anyway.

Comment: This is a **very** informative post Hans, thanks. The rating of `CloseReason` you've list is actually something I've had in the back of my mind. And when I hit this scenario, my suspicions grew even stronger. It's nice to get it confirmed.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Int32 = &H112
Private Const SC_CLOSE As Int32 = &HF060
'Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Int32 = &HF030
'Private Const SC_MINIMIZE As Int32 = &HF020
'Private Const SC_RESTORE As Int32 = &HF120
Private _commandClose As Boolean = False


Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If CInt(m.Msg) = WM_SYSCOMMAND Then
        If (m.WParam.ToInt32 And &HFFF0) = SC_CLOSE Then _commandClose = True
    End If
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
End Sub

Private Sub baseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosing(ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs)
    If _commandClose Then DialogResult = ' ...
    MyBase.OnFormClosing(e)
End Sub
```

reference: [MSDN - WM_SYSCOMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

hmm, actually, this does work. but unlike the official docs, `SC_CLOSE` fires for Alt+F4, etc... as well, even though not specifically mentioned.

It does not fire when calling the `Form.Close()` method. therefore, working as intended.

however, it will still return `UserClosing` if you call the `Close()` method, which is by design.

note: `SC_SCREENSAVE` can be used to detect/prevent screensavers, along with `SC_MONITORPOWER`. the documentation on that seems a bit vague.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into answering my question, but this doesn't solve anything. In fact it makes things worse as this suppresses the `SC_CLOSE` messages.

Comment: You are not testing the `wParam` parameter correctly. As the linked documentation says, you check only the four low-order bits; the high-order bits are used by the system internally. `If (m.WParam.ToInt32 And &HFFF0) = SC_CLOSE Then`

Comment: @Codygray, you're correct. sometimes, i forget these exceptions exist for some messages.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå not sure what you mean. SC_CLOSE only fires for the command menu, the X button, and alt+f4. the issue is simply filtering the X button. it does not appear that resetting .CloseReason is possible, so the only way appears to be to trap these messages and set whatever boolean/variable to obtain the desired behaviour.

Comment: @porkchop I think you've gotten it wrong. The `X` button is working fine. The problem lies with the form closing as a result of setting the `DialogResult` of the form.

Comment: inb4; `UserClosing` is only set when calling `Close()`. and also as a result of alt+f4, x button and command menu. i'm pretty sure that's it. i can't find the exact MSDN doc that references that. also, clicking the x button sets `DialogResult.Cancel` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx i don't see what the problem is... working as intended... and the rest of your answer is in there too.

Comment: and this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx still can't find that other document though. and here is `Form.Closing()` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, which mentions, use the `Closing` event handler to set the `DialogResult`. so basically set a flag in WndProc, and handle it normally, then switch the `DialogResult` when closing...

Comment: right now, it's not even clear to me what exactly you want each button to do, least of all, the x button. ;p but that should cover it. also, notice that a modal dialog is never actually `Closed` until you call `Dispose()`.

Comment: hmmm, well `FormClosingEventArgs`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx mentions that `Close()` calls the `FormClosing` event... lol... but i can't find any mention of it setting the `UserClosing` reason, although that is the case.

Comment: All info in the links you've provided are well known to me. Calling `Form.Close` will set the *stored* close reason to `UserClosing`. But as you know, the `CloseReason` enumeration contains 7 members. Yes, a modal dialog is hidden when calling close, This is basic knowledge. If you've read my update you'll know that setting the `DialogResult` will **not** result in a `WM` being sent. Now, look at your answer. How will overriding the `WndProc` be of any use?

Comment: ok, well at least now it's clear you want to prevent ok and cancel buttons? :D or maybe not... i'm confused..

Comment: All I want is the `CloseReason` to be correct! :) Nothing more, nothing less. And as you can see in my question, this is not the case. Setting the `DialogResult` can result in an "invalid" close reason.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It persists, possible because it is unknown when exactly you will want to enumerate it. or in the case of a modal, maybe even after it is hidden. not sure what the reason for that logic is. some internal pointer. but as a quick hack is can think of checking the reason, using the result, and using `.ShowDialog()` to show it again.

Comment: oh and this is regarding your `DialogResult` observation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65ad5907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx maybe that will help... a bit... lol... here is the mother-list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2chz8edb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx