# set caret position to last character in masked text box - winform?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a masked textbox with input mask as A-00-000-0000 
It gets data from database. Like 
 [image: Masked TextBox]

Is there any way to set caret position to specific position as mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After optimizing my codes, my logic is to move caret at desired location, independen of mask, And remove string after that location..

```
''' <summary>
'''  Set Caret Position to specific location and remove data After given Location
''' </summary>
''' <param name="MaskedTb"> Masked textbox</param>
''' <param name="Loct99">Location (Index) after which remove occured and caret is set</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Sub FocsToMaskedTb( MaskedTb As MaskedTextBox, ByVal Loct99 As Integer)
    If MaskedTb.Text.Length >= Loct99 Then
        MaskedTb.Text = MaskedTb.Text.Remove(Loct99)
    End If
    MaskedTb.SelectionStart = MaskedTb.MaskedTextProvider.LastAssignedPosition + 1
    '' I am using MaskedTextProvider Property
    '' If there is nothing in TextBox, MaskedTb.MaskedTextProvider.LastAssignedPosition = -1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna try something like this:

```
textBox1.Focus();
textBox1.SelectionStart = 8;
textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

(selectionStart sets the position - length is 0 so nothing is selected).

so in your case, you'd set SelectionStart to 8, then to 3, then to 7...

make sure to set focus to this textBox/Maskedtextbox first, otherwise it won't work...

Edit:
you'll have to make sure that after setting the text to the values from the DB, the caret-position is calculated respecting the mask-characters.

Edit2:
like this i can set the Position wherever i want - just, 4 will set the position to position 4 respecting the mask. If i omit SelectionStart and SelectionLength, the caret is positioned automatically to the last character inserted by the first line.

```
maskedTextBox1.Text = "A018";
maskedTextBox1.Focus();
maskedTextBox1.SelectionStart = 7;
maskedTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: It will not work because there is mask as A-00-000-000. if there is nothing in textbox, it will show " -  -   -" as text and its length will be 9.

Comment: i've just setup a small test-project (using exactly your mask). The text shows "- - -"  - but with the appropriate spaces inbetween - therefore the Text has the correct length, and the caret-position is set as required.

Comment: i edited my answer - i hope this answers the problem in your question

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a reverse loop and check each char. If it's not a `Hyphen` nor a `Space` then you've reached the end of the input string.

```vb
Dim text As String = Me.MaskedTextBox1.Text
Dim index As Integer = 0
Dim character As Char = Nothing

For index = text.Length To 1 Step -1
    character = text.Chars((index - 1))
    If ((character <> "-"c) AndAlso (AscW(character) <> 32)) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

Me.MaskedTextBox1.Focus()
Me.MaskedTextBox1.[Select](index, 0)
```

Comment: its too complex because there are more than 20 Masked textbox with different type of masks.. Thanks..

Comment: @ErMayank What is too complex? My code or the 20 *new* masks that is not relevant to this question? You can always place this code in an (extension) method like `Public Sub AutoSetCursor(box As MaskedTextBox)`. Just replace `Me.MaskedTextBox1` with `box`. If one of your new masks fails with this code then ask a new question as my code perfectly answers this one.

Comment: I appreciate you code, but i found a better way to do that without any loop, and in a single line..